# iosnoop does not show devices

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, sip

I have SIP disabled on Catalina. Running `iosnoop` does not show devices:

```
 sudo iosnoop -e
DEVICE    UID   PID D    BLOCK   SIZE       COMM PATHNAME
??        501  5824 R 37998200 262144 com.apple.WebKit ??/VM/swapfile4
??        501  5824 R 39806386 258048 com.apple.WebKit ??/VM/swapfile4
??          0   106 R 45203531 262144       logd ??/VM/swapfile0
??        501   365 R 24331486 262144 LogiMgrDaemon ??/VM/swapfile0
```

Same  `iotop`

I've looked up online and it seems SIP is the only thing that could be preventing these programs to run, but it's in fact disabled:

```
$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

Any ideas why I can't see devices?

[I've found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191708/why-iosnoop-io-snooping-files-on-disk-returns-paths-with-question-marks) but not sure how much does this answer my question.